# Casting implemented class with interface using this operator

Tags: java, interface, casting, this

```
interface iMyInterface {
    public iMethod1();
}

public class cMyClass implements iMyInterface{
    public iMethod1() {
        System.out.println("From Method1");
    }
    protected iMethod2() {
        System.out.println("From Method2");
    }
}

class AppMain
{
    iMyInterface i=new cMyClass();
    public static void main(){
    i.iMethod1();
    ((cMyClass)i).iMethod2();
    }
}
```

this produce output as follows

From Method1

From Method2

becoz interface object is casted to that class

but my question is i cannot cast in this following case

```
class AppMain
{
    iMyInterface i=new cMyClass();
    public static void main(){    
    i.iMethod1();
    this.((cMyClass)i).iMethod2();
    }
}
```

Eclipse IDE shows following error:
Syntax error on token ".", Identifier expected after this token.

i don't understand this 
in either way i accessing the same field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just casting at the wrong point. You want:

```
((cMyClass) this.i).iMethod2();
```

Not that you *have* a `this` to refer to in a static method like `main` in your example...

(Also note that none of your types etc follow Java naming conventions...)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
((cMyClass)(this.i)).iMethod2();
```

You see, your `this` doesn't have `(cMyClass)i` in it, it has just an `i`. So you get that `i` (`this.i`) and cast it to whatever you want.